# Nested class access to enclosing class members

Tags: c++, c++11, inner-classes

From C++ Primer 5th edition By Stanley Lippman et al(19.5):

> A nested class can have the same kinds of members as a nonnested class. Just like any other class, a nested class controls access to its own members using access specifiers. The enclosing class has no special access to the members of a nested class, and **the nested class has no special access to members of its enclosing class**.

Is there any truth to the bolded part? I could find no mention of the nested class being restricted access to enclosing class members in the standard (9.7 N3337) and the following code compiles fine (g++ 5.2.0)

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{
private:
    typedef int woah;
public:
    struct B{
        woah x = 5;
        void test() { A f; std::cout << f.x;}
    };
private:
    int x = 5;
};

int main(){
    A::B j;
    j.test();
}
```

**There being two parts here:**

1. `B` accesses the private type alias `woah` to define its own member.
2. The member function `test` of `B` accesses the private `x` member of an `A` object.

Of course the opposite seems to be true as the quote says: `A` cannot access private members of `B` (not that this example shows that). So is this a blunder on my book's part or am I misunderstanding what it is saying?

Comment: _"I could find no mention of the nested class being restricted access to enclosing class members in the standard"_ You can't find mention of it not being restricted, either.

Answer (score 2):

It was decided that the lack of access of nested classes was a mistake in the Standard, and subsequently rectified. Now nested classes enjoy the same levels of access as all members, namely total access.