# Why can I call private functions from a sub class

Tags: c++

I put a class into another class. I put a reference of the highest level class into the lower level class (not sure if there's a nomenclature for this.. not child/parent..? subclass?). I am very surprised to see that I can call private functions from that sub class. Why is this possible?

Simple example: I am surprised Bar can call a private function from Foo

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Foo {
    public:
        class Bar {
            public:
                Bar(Foo &foo);
                void DoFoo();
            private:
                Foo &foo;
        };

        Foo();
    private:
        void Do();
};

Foo::Foo(){}
void Foo::Do(){
    std::cout << "im doing foo";   
}
Foo::Bar::Bar(Foo &foo)
:foo(foo)
{

};
void Foo::Bar::DoFoo(){
    this->foo.Do();
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    Foo::Bar bar(foo);
    bar.DoFoo();
}
```

Comment: What you have is called a "Nested Class": https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types

Comment: Related, but not sure if it should be considered a duplicate: [Nested class access to enclosing class members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34976995/nested-class-access-to-enclosing-class-members)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually access restrictions do not matter that much here, because (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access), emphasize mine)...

> All members of a class (bodies of member functions, initializers of member objects, **and the entire nested class definitions**) have access to **all names** the class can access.

In your example `Bar` is a [nested class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types) that can access all members of `Foo` (independent of whether they are declared `private`).

**PS** Note that this does not imply that also `Foo` has access to all members of `Bar`. For example `Bar::foo` is only visible within `Bar` because it is declared `private`.

Comment: Worth noting that it doesn't work the other way around.

Comment: @sweenish well, being nested is also not commutative ;), but agreed I'll add a note